# Get video duration without playing?

Tags: c#, wpf, video

I am using `MediaTimeline` and `MediaClock` to control the WMV video playback.

```
Timeline = new MediaTimeline(new Uri(VideoFileName));
Clock = Timeline.CreateClock(true) as MediaClock;
```

When I look at the `Clock.NaturalDuration`, value is set to `Automatic` and does not
contain duration `TimeSpan` yet.

When I assign `Clock` to `MediaElement` and video starts playing, I can now see the `NaturalDuration.TimeSpan` is present and OK.

Is there a way to get the video duration other than assigning clock to media element and playing?

Is there a way to get duration even without usage of media element (this would be the best)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had similar need to check out video length, so I read that this property is available when MediaOpened event is being raised, otherwise is set to Automatic - read this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.naturalduration(v=vs.95).aspx

```
media.MediaOpened += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(media_MediaOpened);
            media.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
            media.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
            media.Play();

void media_MediaOpened( object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            progress.Maximum = (int)media.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
            timer.Start();
            isPlaying = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

getting duration of video file in Win Rt App or Metro C#

```
string path = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
StorageFile videoFile = 
        await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(presentationItem.Slide_path_local);
Windows.Storage.FileProperties.VideoProperties x = 
        await videoFile.Properties.GetVideoPropertiesAsync();
Duration videoDuration = x.Duration;
```

Best way to get duration of video file

Answer (score 0):

Check the HasTimeSpan property to make sure it exists

```
private void Element_MediaOpened1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mediaElement_1.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
                timelineSlider.Maximum = mediaElement_1.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
        }
```